# Nomenclature sorting italic

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{6cm}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\include{abbrevations}
\printnomenclature

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

abbrevations.tex

```
\nomenclature{g}{grams(s)}
\nomenclature{abs}{absolute}
\nomenclature{min}{minute(s)}
\nomenclature{\textit{n}}{normal}
\nomenclature{w}{weak}
```

[image]

It is not sorting properly. The 'n' should come after 'min'. The problem occurs because of \textit{}. How could I resolve this issue?

The nomenclature will contain about 100 elements, and 30 of them will be in italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting is obtained by adding a default prefix `a`, so the sort key is `a\textit{n}`. You can override it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{6cm}
\makenomenclature

\nomenclature{g}{grams(s)}
\nomenclature{abs}{absolute}
\nomenclature{min}{minute(s)}
\nomenclature[an]{\textit{n}}{normal}
\nomenclature{w}{weak}

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hint: *don't* use `\include` for inputting the list, but `\input`. In the code above I added the list in the document in order to avoid auxiliary files. The best place is the preamble, in my opinion, so you should use

```
\input{abbreviations}
```